# How can you find out the identity of the logged in user on Power BI iPad App

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

How can you find out the identity of the logged in user on the Power BI iPad App?  The user needs to be logged into Power BI for them to access the reports.

I want to be able to change the filters for the Power BI reports based on the user.

If I can find out who it is or some identifying information such as email address, then that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Power BI doesn't support dynamic slicers like you're asking about. You could suggest this in the PowerBI forums or the at the [ideas forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas).

That said, you could look in to implementing Row Level Security to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is to implement Dynamic Row Level Security.

**Model:**
[image]

**User Table:** Table that contains user detail along with the field on which we will apply security(here email field).

**Country Table:** Table containing columns to be filtered and contains column used in slicer.

**User Country Bridge:** Bridge table that contains permission details, for example user id x having access to country y and z.

**Defining RLS(Row Level Security):**

In Modelling -> Manage Roles, create a new role on Email of User Table by this DAX query which returns the email id of logged in user.

```
[Email] = userprincipalname()
```

**Finalizing:**

Go to PowerBI Service -> Dataset -> Security and add users to the roles created.

In this manner it becomes easy to maintain roles and security by just modifying the bridge table that stores all permission details.